# Hosting Python chat server with ngrok

Tags: hosting, chat

I built a simple chat server in Python and I realized that my ISP provides service with CGN. I want to expose my server, which works on the local network with no problems, to the Internet.

Some people recommended using ngrok. I searched but I couldn't find any relevant information about how to use it with a Python app. I tried running the ngrok tcp port number command and ran the server app at the same time, but it didn't seem to be working.

Is there really any way to expose my server with ngrok? I'm also open to any other ideas about how to host my server.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Openport](https://openport.io/download), you can get a url to your server that is public. In doing so you can host your server.